# Reputation points frozen?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

My reputation points don't seem to be moving up or down. Have my points been frozen for a reason, or is it a bug? Is anyone else experiencing this?

Edit: Is there perhaps a cap on the amount that can be gained in one day? My points have jumped several hundred today.

Comment: There is a cap of 200.

Comment: 200 from upvotes. Can be increased by each +15 for accepted answers, so the cap isn't hard.

Comment: See also here: [Capped reputation](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/701/capped-reputation) and the [faq](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).

Comment: BTW for reaching daily reputation cap you get the [Mortarboard](http://math.stackexchange.com/badges/41/mortarboard) badge (bronze).
If you like badges, you can aim for [Epic](http://math.stackexchange.com/badges/42/epic) (silver) and [Legendary](http://math.stackexchange.com/badges/43/legendary). You get them if you reach the reputation cap 50 times/150 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [faq on reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) says this:

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day. Please note that votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate any reputation, while accepted answers and bounty awards are not subject to the daily reputation limit.